# How to deactivate other stack exchange accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I opened several Stack exchange accounts and they all are showing in my user' page. I am not using them regularly. So I want to remove them from my user page. How to do it?

Comment: you want them to be removed without having to delete them right?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am not using them but they are always in my user home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to remove other StackExchange accounts, you would have to contact the moderators on the associated sites, or visit the pages **on those sites** corresponding to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) for details on  deleting your other accounts.

Comment: "the pages on those sites corresponding to this page" - Not clear.

Comment: @Samprity: The text "this page" is a hyperlink with instructions for deleting your account, but it is a version of the page for math.SE. There is a version of the page on each site.  E.g., the following for Academia: http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account.  This is for if you actually want to delete the accounts, not just change your profile to not show them (which may be impossible for all I know).

Comment: Thank you Sir, I have seen it.

Comment: @Samprity: I don't believe there is a way to keep your other accounts from appearing on your profile page. If there is, someone will probably let us know. However, only your math.SE and four other accounts are shown on your profile page. The same is true on the other sites.

Comment: @robjohn: "only...four other accounts are shown on your profile page."  There is a "view more" link; all of the accounts are easily viewable through the profile page.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: yes, but I assumed that Samprity was concerned about the accounts showing up on the profile page (user page).